# Array of THREADENTRY32 struct as function parameter causes C2061

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, struct

I want to add a method to my debugger which fills a THREADENTRY32 array with all threads of the process being currently debugged. For that, I want to use the method "EnumerateThreads" which I pass a THREADENTRY32 pointer which the function should fill out.

However, I'm having trouble using a THREADENTRY32 pointer as a function parameter.

Everytime I declare a function like this in my header file I receive an C2061 error ("syntax error : identifier 'THREADENTRY32'"):

```
void EnumerateThreads(THREADENTRY32 *threadArray);
```

The header file includes  already which defines the THREADENTRY32 structure if I read that correctly.

Using a custom struct and passing it to the function works without any problems:

struct Test
    {
        int bla;
        DWORD boo;
    };
    [...]
    void EnumerateThreads(Test *test);

I've worked with int-/char-/float-/etc. arrays, but I don't have any experience with struct arrays.
I just wondered why it does work with my own structs but not with the THREADENTRY32 one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:

```
void EnumerateThreads(struct THREADENTRY32 *threadArray);
```

this will inline forward declare the struct, however, you need the full definition from `Tlhelp32.h` where ever you access the members of the struct or use the `sizeof` operator.

alternatively you need to declare the struct (by including the `Tlhelp32.h`) in the same translation unit (but preceding) of the proto and its uses, or provide a forward declaration for the compiler to bind to via `struct THREADENTRY32;`